# Log4j2 CLASS_NOT_FOUND Error for Layout Element in Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j2

I recently migrated to Log4j2 in my Spring Boot project and encountered an error related to the layout configuration in my `log4j2.xml`. Despite following the recommended configuration steps, I'm still facing an issue that I haven't been able to resolve.

**Error Message:**

> ERROR StatusConsoleListener Error processing element Layout ([Console:
> null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND

**log4j2.xml Configuration:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console">
            <Property name="target">System.out</Property>
            <Property name="threshold">INFO</Property>
            <Layout type="PatternLayout">
                <Property name="pattern">%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c{1} [%p] - %m%n</Property>
            </Layout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="warn" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.solacesystems.jcsmp" level="warn" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.solacesystems.jms" level="warn" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

1. **Added Log4j2 Spring Boot Starter Dependency:** Included the spring-boot-starter-log4j2 dependency in my pom.xml and excluded the default spring-boot-starter-logging.
2. **Verified Configuration File Location:** Confirmed that my log4j2.xml is located in src/main/resources, ensuring it's on the classpath.
3. **Checked for Dependency Conflicts:** Reviewed my project's dependencies for any conflicts that might cause class loading
   issues, particularly with Log4j2 classes.

**pom.xml changes:**

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Exclude Spring Boot's default logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Add Log4j2 Starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.21.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.21.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.12</version>
       </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Despite these steps, the error persists. Has anyone encountered this issue before, or does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve the CLASS_NOT_FOUND error related to the layout element in Log4j2 with Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Log4j Core there are two XML configuration variants: a **concise** configuration and a **strict** configuration (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#XML)).

In the concise configuration you use the **tag name** to indicate the component type:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console"
                 target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c{1} [%p] - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    ...
</Configuration>
```

To use the strict configuration, you need to specify the `strict="true"` attribute. This configuration variant allows you to use **any** tag name (e.g. `Layout` as in your example) as long as you specify a `type` attribute:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration strict="true">
    <Appenders>
        <Component type="Console">
            <Param type="name">console</Param>
            <Param type="target">SYSTEM_OUT</Param>
            <Component type="PatternLayout">
                <Param type="pattern">%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c{1} [%p] - %m%n</Param>
        </Component>
    </Appenders>
    ...
</Configuration>
```

The idea behind the strict configuration was that it is easier to validate it with an XML schema. However there is already a manually written schema (cf. [Log4j-config.xsd](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/main/log4j-core/src/main/resources/Log4j-config.xsd)) that covers part of the concise format and soon (cf. [Issue #1954](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/1954)) we'll publish a schema that covers all known component types.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Check Log4j2 Initialization**: Ensure that Log4j2 is initializing correctly when your Spring Boot application starts up. You can enable debug logging for Log4j2 initialization by adding the following line to your application.properties file:

```
logging.level.org.apache.logging.log4j=DEBUG
```

2. **Verify Dependency Versions**: You can use the Maven dependency:tree command to inspect your project's dependency tree and ensure that there are no unexpected versions of Log4j2 or SLF4J being pulled in transitively.

```
mvn dependency:tree
```